Distinguishability of elements through extensions
I was studying field theory when a question came to my mind.
Let's consider a field K and two elements x and y of (one of) its algebraic closure(s) C, and let's call x and y [normally] indistinguishable over K if every subfield L of C containing K [such that L/K is normal] either contains both of them or does not contain both.
My question (a bit vague, I guess) is: how can one characterise (normally) indistinguishable elements?
Two trivial observations are (1) that two elements of K are indistinguishable and (2) that element of K can be distinct from an element not in K. Only a bit less trivially, started thinking about a sufficient condition for normal indistinguishability: elements having the same minimal polynomial over K are normally indistinguishable. But I can't neither prove the converse (is it true?) nor get much further than that, especially in the general case.
How would more expert algebraists approach the question?
EDIT x and y are indistinguishable over K if and only if K(x) = K(y). x and y are normally indistinguishable over K if and only if the extension of K generated by the roots in C of the minimal polynomial of x over K is equal to the extension of K generated by the roots of the minimal polynomial of y over K. What can be added to this?

Generalizing your observations: (a) if $K(x)\ne K(y)$ then $x$ and $y$ are distinguishable; (b) if $x$ and $y$ have the same minimal polynomial over $K$ then $x$ is indistinguishable from $cy+d$ for all rational numbers $c,d$ with $c\ne0$.
